# Почему не находит страницу? Неправильно настроен htaccess? PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, вёрстка

### появилась проблема (скриншоты ниже). Почему это произошло? Всё работало до некоторых внесений в .htaccess, затем эти изменения я удалил но всё ровно такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Потому. Что. [Вторник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error). День. Тяжелый.

Comment: Потому что, что?

Comment: Здравствуйте, вы уверены, что сохранили файл после того, как удалили изменения в .htaccess?

Comment: Да, уверен, появилась такая ошибка `Refused to apply style from… because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported style-sheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled`